# None of [([ ])] are in the columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, keyerror

I keep getting the below keyerror and can't figure out what it means or what I should be doing different.

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['team totals', 'mp_max', 'fg_max', 'fga_max', 'fg%_max', '3p_max',\n       '3pa_max', '3p%_max', 'ft_max', 'fta_max', 'ft%_max', 'orb_max',\n       'drb_max', 'trb_max', 'ast_max', 'stl_max', 'blk_max', 'tov_max',\n       'pf_max', 'pts_max', '+/-_max', 'ts%_max', 'efg%_max', '3par_max',\n       'ftr_max', 'orb%_max', 'drb%_max', 'trb%_max', 'ast%_max', 'stl%_max',\n       'blk%_max', 'tov%_max', 'usg%_max', 'ortg_max', 'drtg_max'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

my code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import os

SEASONS = list(range(2016, 2017))
DATA_DIR = "data"
STANDINGS_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "standings")
SCORES_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "scores")

box_scores = os.listdir(SCORES_DIR)
box_scores = [os.path.join(SCORES_DIR, f) for f in box_scores if f.endswith(".html")]

def parse_html(box_score):
    with open(box_score) as f:
        html = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")] # this removes the tr tag with class over_header from the html
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.thead")]
    return soup

def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pandas.read_html(str(soup), attrs = {"id": "line_score"})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols

    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]
    return line_score


def read_stats(soup, team, stat):
    df = pandas.read_html(str(soup), attrs={"id": f"box-{team}-game-{stat}"}, index_col=0)[0]
    df = df.apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
    return df

def read_season_info(soup):
    nav = soup.select("#bottom_nav_container")[0]
    hrefs = [a["href"] for a in nav.find_all("a")]
    season = os.path.basename(hrefs[1]).split("_")[0]
    return season

base_cols = None
games = []

for box_score in box_scores:
    soup = parse_html(box_score)
    line_score = read_line_score(soup)
    teams = list(line_score["team"]) #grabs just the teams who played each other

    summaries = []
    for team in teams:
        basic = read_stats(soup, team, "basic")
        advanced = read_stats(soup, team, "advanced")

        totals = pandas.concat([basic.iloc[-1:], advanced.iloc[-1:]])
        totals.index = totals.index.str.lower() # to lower case

        maxes = pandas.concat([basic.iloc[:-1,:].max(), advanced.iloc[:-1,:].max()])
        maxes.index = maxes.index.str.lower() + "_max"

        summary = pandas.concat([totals, maxes])

        if base_cols is None:
            base_cols = list(summary.index.drop_duplicates(keep="first"))
            base_cols = [b for b in base_cols if "bpm" not in b]

        summary - summary[base_cols]

        summaries.append(summary)

    summary = pandas.concat(summaries, asix=1).T

    game = pandas.concat([summary, line_score], axis=1)

    game["home"] = [0, 1]
    game_opp = game.iloc[::-1].reset_index()
    game_opp.columns += "_opp"

    full_game = pandas.concat([game, game_opp], axis=1)

    full_game["season"] = read_season_info("soup")

    full_game["date"] = os.path.basename(box_score)[:8]
    full_game["date"] = pandas.to_datetime(full_game["date"], format="%Y%m%d")

    full_game["won"] = full_game["total"] > full_game["total_opp"]

    games.append(full_game)

    if len(games) % 100 == 0:
        print(f"{len(games)} / {len(box_scores)}")
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace, so we can see which line of code is causing this?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details, including a stack trace and sample data.